# Ef Core many to many relation with properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two model classes:

```cs
public class Recording
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Each tag can have many recordings and each recording can have many tags. The problem: The tag is probably not valid for the whole recording but could also be valid over multiple recordings. Something like this would be possible:
Recordings:

| Id | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-17T10:00:00.000 | 2022-10-17T11:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-10-17T11:00:00.000 | 2022-10-17T12:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2022-10-17T12:00:00.000 | 2022-10-17T13:00:00.000 |

One tag could be valid from `2022-10-17T10:10:00.000` to `2022-10-17T10:12:00.000` (part of the time of Recording 1), another one could be valid from `2022-10-17T10:10:00.000` to `2022-10-17T11:30:00.000` (part of recording 1 and part of recording 2) and a third one could be valid from `2022-10-17T10:10:00.000` to `2022-10-17T12:30:00.000` (part of recording 1, complete recording 2 and part of recording 3).

How should I design the table between Recordings and tags? Is there any way EF Core can autogenerate something like that?

My idea would have been a third model class:

```cs
public class RecordingTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public List<Recording> Recordings { get; set; }
}
```

But I am not happy with it at all.

Comment: Your "third model class" (usually referred to as a join entity in this context) is required if you want to include data related to the relationship itself (which is what your `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a common uscase. Detailed example can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration)

Relevent part of the linked page:

```cs
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
            .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
            .UsingEntity<PostTag>(
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                    .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
                    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId),
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
                    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId),
                j =>
                {
                    j.Property(pt => pt.PublicationDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                    j.HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });
                });
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```